# i want to get data from contenteditable div and insert into database how can i do that?

Tags: php, html, editor

is it possible to get data that contain html element from content editable div.

```
<div id="content" class="content" name="content" contenteditable="true" spellcheck="false"\>
<b>hallo</b>world
```

Comment: you will have to use javascript to do that and then send using ajax to server to insert to db

Answer (score 0):

You can use the example below, Press Button Save, It will alert the data stored in div.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<div id="content" class="content" name="content" contenteditable="true" spellcheck="false"\>
<b>hallo</b>world
</div>
<button onClick="textFromDiv()">Save</button>


</body>
<script>
function textFromDiv(){
var divText = document.getElementById('content'),

htmlContent = divText.innerHTML;
alert(htmlContent);
}
</script>

</html>
```

After this you can use the variable htmlContent that contains the data inside the div.

Comment: how i can insert it into database?

Comment: if you are using php you can use @professor-abronsius example, if you need any other help or you want a simpler code, let me know

Answer (score 0):

In order to `insert` the text/html content from a `contendeditable` element within a webpage you will need to use Javascript to either send via ajax ( as suggested earlier ) or send as a regular form submission to the server.

In the following code example the actual content is sent using `fetch` to the server - in this case it simply uses `location.href` to point to itself but in practice this could be a normal script path, such as `/path/to/script.php`

On the server, the PHP script will have access to the `POST` array and specifically `content` via `$_POST['content']` - from which point you can craft the sql statement and commit to db.

eg:

```
<?php
    if( isset( $_POST['content'] ) ){
        $sql='insert into `<TABLE>` ( `content` ) values ( ? )';
        $stmt=$db->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->bind_param('s',$_POST['content']);
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->close();
        exit('ok..');
    }
?>
```

```js
let div=document.querySelector('#content');
let bttn=document.querySelector('input[type="button"]');
    bttn.addEventListener('click',e=>{
      let fd=new FormData();
          fd.set('content',div.innerHTML);

      fetch( location.href, { method:'post', body:fd } )
        .then(r=>r.text())
        .then(console.log)
        .catch(alert)    
    });
```

```html
<div class="content" id="content" contenteditable="true" spellcheck="false">
  hello <b>World!</b> What's occuring?
</div>

<input type='button' value='Get Contents & send to Server' />
```

Note: due to the sandbox restrictions here the snippet will not allow the Fetch request to localhost!